# Balance columns in all document

Tags: multicol

In IEEE documents all the columns are balanced. Is it posible to achieve this in an `article` class?.

Comment: See the `multicols` package.

Comment: You can have a look at the `balance` package.

Comment: I used the multicol, flushend and balance packages but these not works  fine for me

Comment: Andres, it would be really nice if you accepted the most helpful answers to your old questions. See [how to accept an answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/14)

Comment: The more I look at the question (and what the IEEE document classes do) the more I believe the answer to the question is simply: use \flushcolumns with the standard article class.

Comment: Worth to note that  `\flushcolumns` is simple, but using the `multicol` package. for newbies trying this with a standard `twocolumn` article will be only a frustrating undefined control sequence.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In addition to commented `multicols` or `balance` packages and others as `vwcol` (this for a single page), may be a simpler method is the package `flushend`

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{flushend} %balanced columns
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10] 
\end{document}
```

Another option, that could be problematic when using floats and enunciations (theorem, lemma, etc,) is set the `fontsize`, `baseline` and `lines` per page in the whole document with the  `grid` package to fill the empty space of the last page or fit the text to n-1 pages.

For example, in this MWE with a single short column in the third page can be converted to a  document with two or tree pages with no empty spaces:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% for a 2 pages document uncomment this
%\usepackage[fontsize=10pt,baseline=12pt,lines=51]{grid} 
% for a 3 pages document uncomment this
% \usepackage[fontsize=11pt,baseline=14pt,lines=35]{grid}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-16]
\end{document}
```